# haml - How to include 2 divs inside link?

Tags: html, haml

I am trying to include 2 divs inside a link but the second div gets ignored. Any idea how to add 2 divs inside the link using haml?

```
= link_to '#' do
 .div_one
   Content div One
 .div_two
   Content div Two
```

I am getting this output:

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="div_one">Content div One</div>
</a>
<div class="div_two">Content div Two</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like so:

```
%a{:href => "#"}
  .div_one Content div One
  .div_two Content div Two
```

which gives the output

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="div_one">Content div One</div>
  <div class="div_two">Content div Two</div>
</a>
```

but I am without a proper compiler and have resorted to https://haml2erb.org/ so I cannot 100% verify as of right now.